# Accommodating or sidestep dataset and setAttribute typings / purpose of optional typing

Tags: typescript, optional-typing

Q: Is there a way to explicitly state, *globally*, perhaps through a .tds, that in the case of HTMLElement.dataset and setAttribute() that implicit casts from Any to string are acceptable, or that these members accept Any to begin with? I am not interested in flagging each case.

Context: 
I'm new to TS and would like to experiment with an existing project/experiment/prototype that grew big enough to warrant some typing, but that makes extensive use of dataset and setAttribute.

I do not care that my above question contains a bad idea©. Typescript linting has provided me with *immediate* benefits by catching *unintentional* things... but only when I can distinguish these cases from lots of instances of two things done on purpose.

However, I *am* making an assumption that, in general, one human purpose of optional typing among others, philosophically speaking, is to allow a developer to distinguish between bad ideas and accidents. If I'm wrong about that, then I *would* like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you'd like to gradually type your code and (hopefully temporarily) loosen some of the restrictions you can use your own libraries instead of the built-in ones.  Your [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) probably specify a value for `lib` or use the default for your `target` which includes a reference to the built-in [`lib.dom.d.ts` declaration file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).  You don't *have* to use that, so you can choose to make a copy of it and alter it to your heart's content.

In this case, though, since the built-in [`HTMLElement` interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6375-L6397) doesn't *directly* contain the [`setAttribute()` method](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5042) (which is defined in [`the Element interface`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4902)) or the [`dataset` property](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L7844) (which is defined in [`the HTMLOrSVGElement interface`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L7843), you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add your own version of these into `HTMLElement`:

```
// merge into existing HTMLElement interface
interface HTMLElement {
  setAttribute(qualifiedName: any, value: any): void;
  readonly dataset: { [k: string]: any };
}
```

(Note: the above only works if your code is already in the global scope.  If you are writing code within a module, you might need to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) via the `declare global` syntax.)

And use it:

```
function useHTMLElement(x: HTMLElement) {
  x.innerHTML; // okay

  x.setAttribute(123, "hello"); // okay now
  x.dataset.foo = 123; // okay now

  x.getAttribute(123); // error, didn't override HTMLElement.getAttribute
}
```

As you can see, the existing `HTMLElement` definition is there (since `innerHTML` is known to be a property) but your merged method and properties are working as expected (they do not complain about `123` not being a `string`).

Okay, hope that helps.  As I said, hopefully you will consider altering your code at some point to make it conform to the `string` constraint that everyone else expects, especially if the code is going to be used or maintained by others and is not just a personal or toy project.  But that's up to you and is explicitly not what you care about, so I'll leave it at that.

Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEFsFMCcHNNASwHYBcD2pIA9EGdUVZQAJAFQFkAZAUQBtIo0k0YAzAQwGNIAoFVO24Jy1eo0jMA3r1Cg8kVAEFUqaIgBGAV0EAKAI5aOdRG0SQAJgDkOUAFygOyAJ4AaUADdjWyA6fOASgcPdEQLAG5ZUGhIDgt0ZDpnUAsOVA4FVAcpUABtAGsHAnVkWABdPxdQAF9I6t5eNi1kLkIE0C0FUVoGJlRdbAdu8T6A0Bk5bAA6FGQYbvDQEFB0fI5nBsmpzJU1TR1IXQBGACYAZncAIgALSDo6dEuAxeXV9dBkdAB3KOnU9MyUzY6EwAF5QKczi8wG9kp8fr8pvBlKp1No9JDnkswDBoOhoO4LGFkAByVArDy4sIiSg9CRoJGKXZog68epAA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I am indeed using modules so thanks for the tidbit. It is also a personal project so I'm not super concerned with other developers right now. I'll come back to accept this answer as soon as I get a chance to try this out!